# PQRS is a parallelogram and G and H are midpoints of QR and RS respectively. PG and PH meet QS at A and B respectively. Prove that QA = AB = BS.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

PQRS is a parallelogram and G and H are midpoints of QR and RS respectively. PG and PH meet QS at A and B respectively.

Prove that QA = AB = BS.[image]

Comment: 1) Why should I prove it? 2) What have you tried to prove it? 3) Have you tried drawing it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $PR\cap QS=\{O\}$.

Thus, $QO$ and $PG$  are  medians of $\Delta PQR$.

Thus, $$QA:AO=2:1.$$
Similarly, $$SB:BO=2:1$$ and since $QO=OS,$ we are done!

For example. Let $AO-x$ and $BO=y$.

Hence, $$3x=QO=OS=3y,$$
which says $x=y$ and $QA=AB=BS.$

Comment: Can you explain the first line of your solution.

Comment: @AMAN $A$ is a common point of medians of $\Delta PQR$, which says $QA:AO=2:1.$ See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)

Comment: the very first line of your solution, what does that mean ?

Comment: @AMAN It means that $O$ is a common point of $PR$ and $QS$.